# ios storyboard tabbar > ViewController > TableView

Tags: ios, tableview, tabbar, viewcontroller

I would like to create the following navigation

I have a tab bar program build with storyboard
and I have a View controller with buttons
when I click a button A navigation controller is called

Right now I have made all the connections and everything works fine but..
in order to create the change from the button to the table view I am using modal segue and that removes my tab bar.
I know that push will not work cause its not a navigation but how can I work this out?

Comment: you might want to check this out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but I realized that the best option is do it using a push segue. It's the best option because when you have a table view into a tab bar item it's more usability, it's what customer want. I'm sorry for not solution your problem but I strongly recomend you to use push.

Comment: Thats the closest to the answer I have implement :)